# Apache Artemis - libartemis-native-64.so shipped vs manually created - are both same

Tags: activemq-artemis

The Apache Artemis tar.gz ships with a `bin/lib/linux-x86_64/libartemis-native-64.so` which i was not aware until i manually used the native source to create that .so file.

Question:

- There is a `libartemis-native-64.so` shipped with the tar - is this any different from generating from the source code on the specific Linux box where the broker runs?
- Can i use the `libartemis-native-64.so` native library shipped with the tar.gz, is there any impact.
- The generated native lib is different in size compared the the shipped one.
- If we need to use the generated native library, do we need to simply replace the one under $ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/lib/linux* location?
- Finally, how to verify if the native library is used by the broker, in my case i don't see any info on the Logs. only see using AIO message.

```
2020-08-14 12:24:16,226 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server
2020-08-14 12:24:16,269 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
2020-08-14 12:24:16,662 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221055: There were too many old replicated folders upon startup, removing /brokers/broker1/data/bindings/oldreplica.1
2020-08-14 12:24:16,663 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222162: Moving data directory /brokers/broker1/data/bindings to /brokers/broker1/data/bindings/oldreplica.3
2020-08-14 12:24:16,667 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221055: There were too many old replicated folders upon startup, removing /brokers/broker1/data/journal/oldreplica.1
2020-08-14 12:24:16,671 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222162: Moving data directory /brokers/broker1/data/journal to /brokers/broker1/data/journal/oldreplica.3
2020-08-14 12:24:16,673 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221055: There were too many old replicated folders upon startup, removing /brokers/broker1/data/paging/oldreplica.1
2020-08-14 12:24:16,674 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222162: Moving data directory /brokers/broker1/data/paging to /brokers/broker1/data/paging/oldreplica.3
2020-08-14 12:24:16,703 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
2020-08-14 12:24:16,706 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222007: Security risk! Apache ActiveMQ Artemis is running with the default cluster admin user and default password. Please see the cluster chapter in the ActiveMQ Artemis User Guide for instructions on how to change this.
2020-08-14 12:24:16,716 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 2,147,483,648
2020-08-14 12:24:16,763 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2020-08-14 12:24:16,763 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
```

Below is the steps i followed, in case if it helps others.

- Downloaded native source file from [Link](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?filename=activemq/activemq-artemis-native/1.0.2/activemq-artemis-native-1.0.2-source-release.zip&action=download)
- updated the latest package in the Linux VM (RHEL dist) as mentioned in the docs

```
$ sudo yum install libtool gcc-c++ gcc libaio libaio-devel make
```

- Extracted the code to `apache-artemis-native-1.0.2` folder, within that folder used below command to create the .so file

```
  $ ./scripts/compile-native.sh
  // This command threw compilation error for missing gnu/stubs.h (which i think is 32-bit dependency)
```

Above command created the libartemis-native-64.so on the target/ folder. (32-bit library was not created due to compilation error)

- I was exploring ways to set this library to `java.library.path` on borker instance.
- Noticed the broker1/bin/artemis shell script refers to `java.library.path` to the artemis-2.14.0 (extracted tar.gz location) bin/lib path.
- I copied the libartemis-nativie-64.so to this location, assuming it will be picked up by the broker instance.

below is the content of broker-instance broker1/bin/artemis content.

```
exec "$JAVACMD" \
    $JAVA_ARGS \
    -Xbootclasspath/a:"$LOG_MANAGER:$WILDFLY_COMMON" \
    -Djava.security.auth.login.config="$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC/login.config" \
    $ARTEMIS_CLUSTER_PROPS \
    -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
    -Dartemis.home="$ARTEMIS_HOME" \
    -Dartemis.instance="$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE" \
    -Djava.library.path="$ARTEMIS_HOME/bin/lib/linux-$(uname -m)" \
    -Djava.io.tmpdir="$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE/tmp" \
    -Ddata.dir="$ARTEMIS_DATA_DIR" \
    -Dartemis.instance.etc="$ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC" \
    -Djava.util.logging.manager="$ARTEMIS_LOG_MANAGER" \
    -Dlogging.configuration="$ARTEMIS_LOGGING_CONF" \
    $DEBUG_ARGS \
    org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis "$@"
```

Comment: How come you're compiling your own version of the Artemis Native?

Comment: Per the documentation I followed the steps.. https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/libaio.html

-- after locally able to generate the libaretmis-native-64.so file, I noticed already similar .so file is shipped with tar.gz. just wanted to understand bit more on that.

Comment: For what it's worth, the documentation you cited clearly states that the broker ships with .so files, and that you only need to compile them yourself if your using a platform other than Linux x86-64. It doesn't appear you're using such a platform. Can you clarify?

Comment: I was about to do that since in my case i noticed Paging related logs, when Artemis broker  was running for long time and load was bit high, it shuts down the instance  throwing Thread dumps. 
-
 WARN  .. AMQ222033: Page file 000000004.page had incomplete records at position 3,163,289 at record number 1,200

 WARN  .. AMQ222288: Page 4, message 1,200 could not be found on offset 3,163,289, with starting message 1,200. This represents a logic error or inconsistency on the data, and the system will try once again from the beggining of the page file.
-

Comment: For our requirement, i am using persistence enabled, but at very high load, noticing the warning messages. Also the Thread dump indicated libaio realted 
------
"Thread-3 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@4d0f2471)" Id=70 BLOCKED on org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.SoftValueLongObjectHashMap@2b099810 owned by "Thread-17 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@4d0f2471)" Id=111
 at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.cursor.impl.PageCursorProviderImpl.getPageCache(PageCursorProviderImpl.java:168)

Comment: Those errors aren't related to AIO as far as I can tell. What does compiling the Artemis Native have to do with these errors? Please clarify.

Comment: The link I quoted in the comment states the library name as libActiveMQAIO32.so, after compiling and generating the file I noticed the tar.gz file with libartemis-native-64.so. referring to the latest link  (https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/libaio.html) the correct file name is listed. That is where I got confused. Only after your first response I realized I referred to a old document link.

Comment: Eventually that is one of the reason I raised this question.